# What should be the data type of deleted fields?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

While database design I used a field name deleted and use it as Boolean.  Everything seems fine.

I’m using hibernate 3.6.9. So I’ve configured **applicationContext**

> > prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true=1 false=0

In my sessionFactory bean.  So when Im saving my object, it converting my Boolean as 1/0. 
So but problem is when Im retrieving object from database, Im getting

> > java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean

Can any of you tell how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `hibernate.query.substitutions` only work for queries, but not for entities.

What I would try is to implement a Custom User Type that maps a boolean to 1 or 0. And than use that custom user type to annotate the boolean field of my entity.

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Typ(type="com.example.Boolean01Type")
private boolean deletes;
```

Have a look at this [blog](http://java.dzone.com/articles/annotating-custom-types) for an example how to implement a custom type. (*I am not 100% sure, but I remember that there was somehow two concepts of custom types in hibernate, one more powerful than the other*)

But definitely have a look at the standard custom type "yes_no", that is really close to the one you need to write.

```
 @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="yes_no")
 boolean myBoolean;
```